# Flash messages not showing when using 'render' after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have trouble getting a flash message to show after a failed form submit.

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @question do |q| %>

  <p>
    <b>Your question</b><br />
    <%= q.text_field :title, :size => 48 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>Add more details</b><br />
    <%= q.text_area :body, :size => "80x10" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= q.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And this is the part of the controller handling it:

```
def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(params[:question])
    if @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path, :flash => { :success => "Your question was saved!" }
    else
      flash.now[:alert => "There was a problem when trying to save your question!"]
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The template file for the `new` action contains nothing but the form above.

I am currently using this code snippet (in `application.html.erb`) to display flash messages, and it works for the flash message after a successful save and redirecting to `index`:

```
  <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
      <div class="<%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
  <% end %>
```

I have not been able to find a solution to this problem myself, so I'm hoping a more experienced pair of eyes will be able to spare what I assume to be just a few minutes to enlighten me.

Thanks!

P.S.: I have also tried a regular `flash[:key => "value"]` as well as `render 'new', :flash => {:alert => "There was a problem when trying to save your question!"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that by this:

```
flash.now[:alert => "There was a problem when trying to save your question!"]
```

You meant this:

```
 flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem when trying to save your question!"
```

Comment: If only I would have ... that was the one variant I didn't give a try yet. Problem solved, thanks!